# How to re-structure this to wait for / catch completion of queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Yet another incidence of "I'm sure there's a nice way to do this, but I just can't see it..."

We have a function that iterates through some things, makes a list, then (optionally) splits it into chunks, then uses `$.get()` to query the server and populate the page with the returned data.

However, due to the async nature of ajax, the `$.get()` returns immediately, which messes stuff up.

Pseudocode is something like this:

```
function get_all_the_things()
{
    var total = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        $(".things").each(function()
        {
            list += this; // Add thing to list
            total++;
            if(list.length > 500)
            {
                // Keep list <500 entries
                return(false); // break out from this each(function()
            }
        });

        if(list.length > 0)
        {
            $.get("thingdata.cgi",list,function(reply)
            {
                // Update page with data
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // No things / no more things
            break;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

We want to keep this function in this sort of form so we can call it from various places to refresh the page, something like this:

```
$("#table_of_all_things").hide();
get_all_the_things();
$("#table_of_all_things").show();
```

To stop the user fiddling with any `$(".things")` while updating is happening. However, because of the async nature, the function returns immediately and therefore everything is shown again before being updated.

One benefit of the `while(true)` style is that it will loop round until running out of `$(".things")` to add, and launch parallel `$.get`s rather than chaining one after the other.

I'm struggling (mainly through over-exposure to RGB radiation + caffeine) to see how to re-structure this so it only returns once finished, without ending up just chaining one `$.get` after another until finished.

Comment: There's a simple rule with AJAX: Anything that depends on the response has to be done from the callback function. So put `$(".things").show()` in the callback.

Comment: We can't do it like that, the example is simplified but, as an example, $(".things") are a load of items in a table and we want to hide the table, update the things, then show the table. Also, as each query only updates a certain number of things, we need to wait for all of them to be updated before showing any of them.

Comment: I have updated to reflect the (hoped for) usage.

Comment: You may need to make use of `Deferred`. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with them, so can't give specific advice.

Comment: You could work with a request-counter. meaning count the requests you do and count the answers you get. if the answers have same count as requests, you are done. would that work?

Comment: @Homungus That's sort of what I've tried, but how do you stop the function returning other than something like `while(reqs_waiting > 0)` which just ends up locked in a loop & causes the browser concern your script has crashed.

Comment: @JohnU you can use recursion, call your funcionton the complete of the get

Comment: You have to check your `reqs_waiting` in the callback function. like `if (reqs_waiting == 0) $("#table_of_all_things").show(); `

Comment: NkSP and Homungus, would you be able to expand those comments into an answer to show how it hangs together? I hate to sound lazy, but I am keen to understand this & get it right rather than just _think_ I have and end up doing it badly.